# How can I change the font size of a GWT Label object dynamically?

Tags: java, gwt, font-size

In a GWT project, I want to be able to do something like this, to set the font size that'll be used for an instance of a Label:

```js
public class BigLabel extends Label {
    public BigLabel(String s, int i) {
      super(s);
      setFontSize(i); // sets font size in em units
    }
}
```

But I can't because I can't find any method that does the same job. I can easily use `Label.setStyleName`, but if I do that I have to set it to an absolute value stored in the css file. Is there a way to have a font size that's flexible?

Comment: I'm sorry, I probably don't mean 'dynamically' in my question. I'm not after text that can resize itself, but I want to be able to supply the size at the time I create the text object. Perhaps 'programatically' is a better word.

Answer (score 10):

```java
private void setFontSize(double ems) {
  getElement().getStyle().setFontSize(ems, Unit.EM);
}
```